# Blackmagic Cinema Camera: recording, bitrate and bitdepth

Tags: camera, video-recording

If connecting a Blackmagic Cinema Camera via Thunderbolt to a laptop, can you record directly to the harddrive of the laptop? Which bitrate does have these recordings if using ProRes HQ422 at 1920x1080 @25p? And what's the real bitdepth of the image you get in this setup?

Comment: Just real life experiences. The specs are well known.

Comment: What do you mean by *real* bitdepth? The bit depth is there in the specs of the codec - ProRes422-HQ is 10 bit. It's not something you can fudge.

Answer (score 1):

The Media Express software it ships with will let you capture video directly from the Thunderbolt port at 23.98p, 24p, 25p, 29.97p, 30p frame rates ([from the tech specs page](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/blackmagiccinemacamera/techspecs/))

[From the Wikipedia ProRes 422 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProRes_422) you will get 10-bit sample depth, and High-Quality comes in at 220 Mbit/s for HD resolution at 60i

Thunderbolt can handle 10Gb/s and SATA 3 can handle 6Gb/s so they will not be a bottleneck here.

Comment: I asked for a certain setup. Do you have experience with that camera?